# Haxe - Class not found : Main

Tags: javascript, haxe, cocktail.js

I try to use haxe and cocktail for the first time.
I follow this tutorial : http://www.silexlabs.org/haxe/cocktail/tutorials/getting-started-with-cocktail/

Main.hx

```
import js.Lib;
import js.Dom;

class Main
{
    static inline var ICON_COCKTAIL_PATH:String = "assets/icone_cocktail_blanche_ombre.png";
    static inline var ICON_HAXE_PATH:String = "assets/icone_haxe_blanche_ombre.png";

    static function main()
    {
        #if !js
        //init cocktail and load the "index.html" file in the bin folder
        cocktail.api.Cocktail.boot();
        #end

        //html and css loaded
        Lib.window.onload = function(e) new Main();
    }

    public function new()
    {
        // get the image node
        var image:Image = cast Lib.document.getElementById("icon");

        // create interactivity
        image.onmouseup = function(event:Event) {
            // if image source is cocktail icon, change it to Haxe one
            if (image.src.indexOf(ICON_COCKTAIL_PATH) != -1)
                image.src = ICON_HAXE_PATH;
            // if image source is not cocktail icon, change it back to cocktail
            else
                image.src = ICON_COCKTAIL_PATH;
        }
    }
}
```

compile.hxml

```
-main Main
-cp ../src
-js ../bin/Main.js
```

I have following folder structure:

```
\Helloworld
    \bin
        \assets
            \icone_cocktail_blanche_ombre.png
            \icone_haxe_blanche_ombre.png
        \app.css
    \build
    \src
        \index.html
        \Main.hx
    \compile-js.hxml
```

But when I try to compile :

```
haxe compile.hxml 
Class not found : Main
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your compile.hxml should look like this. Note the path to src folder. I believe this is related to hxml file location.

```
-main Main
-cp src
-js bin/Main.js
```